# How can I restrict the coverage.svg to a stage or remove coverage reporting from a stage?

Tags: code-coverage, gitlab-ci

I was just very shocked to see that one of my web projects coverage dropped quite a bit after I introduced end-to-end tests. Those tests do not contribute anything to line coverage as they test against another environment and thus pytest cannot know which lines were covered.

I've marked those lines with `@pytest.mark.e2e` and I have two stages in my GitlabCi pipeline:

```
stages:
  - test
  - route-tests

Unit Tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - pytest -m "not e2e"
  artifacts:
    reports:
      cobertura: cobertura-coverage.xml

Route Tests:
  stage: route-test
  script:
    - pytest -m e2e
```

Surprisingly, both GitlabCI stages coverage is in the analytics:

[image]

Although only the `test` stage has the cobertura reports section, somehow both are in gitlab. How can I disable the coverage reporting for the `route-test` stage? Or is it possible to restrict the [test coverage report badge](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#test-coverage-report-badge) to the `test` stage?

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around, I just made sure that only a single gitlab stage produces a coverage report / file.